# How can I get the following items from a list with entity framework?

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework, take

I have a very large list and I want to extract in parts of 50 items for which I will implement the following:

```
try
{
    using (var context = new ccoFinalEntities())
    {
        return context.sales
            .Where(p => true == p.status && myID == p.id)
            .Take(50)
            .ToList();
    }
}
catch
{
    return null;
}
```

I assume this will return me the first 50 items, my question is:

How can I get the next 50 and so on until extract the list completely?

Any comments or suggestions are welcome

Comment: FIrst time you call `return`, your method will exit and you will need to cal the method again.

Comment: Use Select(x,i) => where 'i' is the index.  Then use GroupBy i/50 to get groups of 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<Item> GetDate(int page, int size = 50)
    {
    try
    {
      using (var context = new ccoFinalEntities())
      {
        return context.sales.Where(p => true == p.status && myID == p.id)
                            .Skip(page * size).Take(size).ToList();
      }
    }
    catch
    {
      return null;
    }
}
```

Then call:

```
GetData(0);
GetData(1);
GetData(2);
GetData(3);
```

.....

`Skip` ignore first `page * size` (1 * 50, 2 * 50, ...) items and `Take` `size` (50) item

Comment: "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."

Comment: @FabiánRomo Impossible. Make sure you call `ToList()` before disposing and make sure you eager load reference properties.

Comment: "The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entites. The methos 'OrderBy' must be called before the methos 'Skip'"